# The resolution of annoying 60 fps cap - vertical sync adaptation

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

"If the monitor can't go past 60hz, then it won't go past it.
V-sync leaves your computer at a cap of 60FPS. Your eyes won't notice anything past that, so there's absolutely no reason not to. "

Question scope is how to increase FPS while using Vertical Synchronization from 60 fps to 100 fps.

We are talking about difference between 60 fps - 100 fps, not past 100 which my eyes finally dont care.

*Context System(just to state that everything fine here)*

GTX680 ; i7; 12GB RAM

*Resolution by increasing refresh rate of the monitor*

I can create custom resolution in the NVDIA control panel and give new refresh rate to the monitor. Hypothetically this should result say to increase in FPS with Vertical Sync ON as GPU should increase the fps to match the monitor refresh rate.

**However I do not know the consequences of doing this, whether this can deal some damage to monitor?**

**And whether monitor is actually able to surpass its cap, or hardware itself is locked to the damn wretched 60 hz?**

*Resolution by buying new monitor*

**Are there monitors like CRT in 90's which have refresh rate say around 120 hz but being LED?**

*Resolution by applying alternative variant of vertical sync*

I am aware of existence of these alternative techniques(like triple-buffering or sort of - maybe incorrect though), but not sure the names or the way they operate so I leave this for you dear experts to suggest me.

Comment: I'm having an extremely hard time trying to figure out what you're asking.  This sounds more like a rant than a question.  Can you clean it up and trim it down, please?

Comment: Np, now better?

Comment: I just want to clarify one point. In your second paragraph you state: "Vertical Synchronization from 60 fps to 100 fps." Should that say **hz** instead of **FPS**?

Comment: asfaik fps, but I am not sure. When we apply VS the result fps measure is shown as 60 max when no VS fps can float up to whatever possible value generated by GPU. So I guess it is fps for measuring resulting frames value and hz for refresh rate in monitor. I am thinking in the result they are the same as they are tied to each other maybe I am wrong?

Comment: FPS are drawn frames, Hz is the maximum possible number of displayed frames.

Comment: V-sync doesn't just cap your FPS, it **syncs** them to match your screen's refresh rate, hence: V-**sync** and not V-**cap**. If it only capped your framerate, that would definitely not be enough to remove tearing. One way to increase your Framerate while still using V-sync, would be enabling Triple Buffering (though that doesn't always work). But why would you want more FPS, if those can't be displayed on your screen anyways?

Comment: I don't know the insight details, but before I tided up a question I included a little ranting about the reason of why I want more. I don't know how it works but it is smoother when increasing from 60fps to 100 fps(turning off vertical sync), so monitor somehow can display more? I am very confused by the matter, but now I clearly know that 120hz 3D monitors FTW to play with 120 fps and V-Sync ON. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are [120Hz monitors](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Description=120hz%20monitor&Submit=ENE) on the market, mostly due to Nvidia 3D. Having more FPS than your monitor can display will have no effect on what you can see, but if the game's tick rate is bound to FPS and not capped then the game may react more snappily to your input.

The effects of forcing your monitor to work at a higher frequency are likely to range from inconsequential to disastrous, and it is unlikely to produce a good result - making a higher frequency monitor is expensive, and there's no point selling one as a standard frequency monitor.

PROTIP: Using triple buffering instead of VSync (double buffering) gives you more FPS at the expensse of VRAM, if your GPU has VRAM to spare it is a free performance boost.

Comment: 3D monitor for this task seems to be overkill. By not capped you mean when VS if off so they are not tied? Yep, that's what I am talking about, I want to generate at least 100 fps and have VS ON. Thanks for contribution.

Comment: A 3D monitor is a monitor that runs at 120Hz. If you want to see more than 60 frames per second being displayed, you will need a monitor that works at over 60Hz. Yes, limiting your FPS with vsync would also limit your tickrate if they are tied.

Comment: I am a little confused about the result image. To put in words: "120 hz and I have to strictly put my glasses on?" or "120 hz and the image is still not "duo" and I can continue to look as normal without glasses" finally resulting in "120 fps max fps" - right?. Apologies I am not knowledgeable about 3D displays.

Comment: You won't need glasses to use a 120Hz monitor at 120Hz if you don't want the 3D effect.

Comment: Here you are the knowledge source! :-) Waited for 'edits' like this. Great, but Triple Buffering only increases my average FPS with the same cap of 60 fps? And in 3D settings it seems I can do both VS and Triple Buffering - how's that works? In fact it is even suggested to turn on triple buffering while using VS.(Thanks a lot)

Comment: Triple buffering doesn't cap your FPS, unlike VSync. Different games structure their double/triple buffering options differently (I prefer a 3-item select: off, double, triple), but it is impossible to do double and triple buffering at the same time, so there's no generic approach. Try enabling triple buffering and disabling VSync, if for some reason that causes tearing try with VSync on.

Comment: hm very interesting - triple buffering. There is no tearing, fps is slightly less than usual but is around 140 fps. I am accepting. THX. And will check wiki pages definitely.

Answer (score 0):

Sure there are monitors you can buy that have a high refresh rate.  Are you sure you have your monitor at its highest Hz? Something like [this monitor](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824116479) will do you good.

Comment: Um.... What is that

Comment: It's a link to a 120Hz monitor.  But the link thought it would be cool to bring a "-pla--LCD+Monitors-_-N82E16824116479&gclid=CIzIyrjRt7cCFU7hQgodsDYACA">" wuth it.

Comment: It's a... link?

Comment: This is a link: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16824116479&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleAdwords&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleAdwords--pla--LCD+Monitors-_-N82E16824116479&gclid=CIzIyrjRt7cCFU7hQgodsDYACA

Comment: SE's link-cleaning code appears to have been choking on the Google AdWords portion of the link (now removed).